# Antonym for "unify" that sounds equally as eloquent?

Tags: american-english, antonyms

Is there an antonym for the word `unify` that sounds just as "eloquent" as the word itself? I feel like `separate` isn't really that great of a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An antonym for unify that sounds equally as eloquent and elegant is "dismantle". It really adds dynamism to anything that you say or write, for example:
"The work of the ingenious war poets was solicitously to dismantle the myths of war, and its beguiled falsified glorifications."

Comment: Although I liked all of the answers, I think this one has the same eloquence but in a very gritty way, which fits well.

Answer (score 2):

disunify

transitive verb dis·unify \"+\

Definition of DISUNIFY:  to destroy the unity of: a :  to bring about a lack of concord or harmony in or among  b :  to break up (a unified whole) into separate often dissident parts

Answer (score 2):

I like "sunder."
Although that sentiment has too few letters for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

May be 'disperse:disseminate:diversify'

## The lips of the wise disperse knowledge.

## The values of human rights movement have disseminated throughout the world.

## unity in diversity

Answer (score 0):

In certain contexts,  "divide"